# Redirecting index.html to an iOS setting (URL in Settings.bundle) for a phonegap project

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to phonegap and iPhone development, and am trying to get phonegap's index.html to redirect to a JQuery Mobile site that is located externally at a settings based URL which I have in my Settings.bundle, Root.plist, Server URL.  I have my index.html page redirecting to a hard coded server in the index.html file, but how do I get it to go to the URL that I have in my application settings?

Thanks in advance for any help in steering me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get the plugin [applicationPreferences](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ApplicationPreferences) working to essentially do something similar. Currently to no avail. As soon as I come up with a solution I will post something here again.

**UPDATE**
This does work it seems. There is a small, nearly unnoticeable error in the readme example. 
There needs to be a comma after the 'homer'.

```
                                                                   ¬
window.plugins.applicationPreferences.set('name_identifier','homer', function() {
        alert("It is saved");
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Failed to retrieve a setting: " + error);
    }
);
```